# How to create an index in elasticsearch such that with every day upload of data it creates a new index alias with date and allow me to delete them

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana

```
PUT myindex-000001
 {
  "aliases": {
  "myindex-alias":{
  "is_write_index": true 
   }
 }
}


 PUT _ilm/policy/my_policy
       {
         "policy": {
         "phases": {
         "hot": {
         "actions": {
          "rollover": {
           "max_size": "25GB" 
      }
    }
  },
  "delete": {
    "min_age": "180d",
    "actions": {
      "delete": {} 
    }
   }
  }
 }
}


PUT _template/my_template
    {
      "index_patterns": ["myindex-*"], 
      "settings": {
       "number_of_shards": 1,
       "number_of_replicas": 1,
        "index.lifecycle.name": "my_policy", 
        "index.lifecycle.rollover_alias": "myindex-alias" 
      }
    }

   POST myindex-000001
    {
     "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
        "number_of_replicas": 1,
           "index.lifecycle.name": "my_policy"
            }
          }
```

I tried to load the data into the elasticsearch index **myindex-alias** from java.

I need to have separate index alias with every new upload date , Ex -

```
         myindex-000001
         myindex-000002
         myindex-000003 and so on..
```

All linked to one policy so that I can delete any alias if I want to.

Answer (score 0):

He, the policy es very similar, just add `"max_age":"1d",` to your payload. See more [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/managing-time-based-indices-efficiently)